# Waiting until nested ajax with a .each() is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There seem to be lots of similar questions about waiting for an ajax call to complete, or waiting for an ajax call to complete with a dynamic number of calls or loops, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine both logic.

I'm trying to do something like this:

1. Ajax call that returns multiple results.
2. For each result, make another Ajax call.
3. Create DOM objects from these secondary calls.
4. Wait until all of these secondary calls are complete so I can manipulate them asynchronously.

```js
function getUserData(tag) {
    var request = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": Math.round(Math.random() * (999999 - 100000) + 100000),
        "method": "UserAdmin.get",
        "params": {
            "api_key": key,
            "tag_id": tag
        }
    };

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/v1/api.php',
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(getUserProfile, ajaxError);
}

function getUserProfile(data) {
    var promises = [];

    $.each(data.result, function (id, value) {
        var request = {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "id": Math.round(Math.random() * (999999 - 100000) + 100000),
            "method": "Profile.getInfo",
            "params": {
                "user_id": id
            }
        };

        var promise = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'api/v1/api.php',
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            dataType: 'json'
        }).then(function (response) {
            var data = response.result;
            var twitch = data.gamerid_twitch;

            if (twitch != '') {
                // This creates dom objects, but can/should be synchronous
                createTwitchStreamer(twitch);
            }
        }, ajaxError);
        promises.push(promise);
    });

    $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function () {
        // I want to be sure everything is done before I run this; asynchronously
        delegateStreamVisibility();
    });
}
```

Everything works, but the `$.when(...` is reporting it finished before it finishes making calls for each result. Some guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need each instance of `createTwitchStreamer()` to run after all requests complete to assure it runs in correct order?

Comment: try `return $.when.apply ...` ? because, as it stands, `getUserProfile` returns undefined

Comment: welcome to SO !

Comment: And how are you *"reporting"* it is finished before others? What you have is structured so that `delegateStreamVisibility()` should only run after all requests are completed

Comment: I don't need `createTwitchStreamer()` to run in any order, and thanks @fr_andres.

`createTwitchStreamer()` reports when it begins and finishes making an element. `delegateStreamVisibility()` seems to be saying it finished after run of `createTwitchStreamer()`

Comment: That is expected order based on code shown. The `then()` inside `each` will run as soon as that request instance completes... `$.when().done()` will run after all requests complete

Comment: I ended my reply abruptly. `delegateStreamVisibility()` finishes after only the first ajax call; after one run of `createTwitchStreamer()`.

Comment: This is possible, @Duckie: only the first subsequent ajax call succeeded, the rest failed. Perhaps people will have more info to help if you describe what you have in `data.result` passed in `$.each`.